# how can the word forlorn be used

Tags: adjectives, word-usage

How can the word *forlorn* be used in a sentence? i know it is an adjective but i hardly see it being used in a passage and really do not how to use it.
 How can it be used correctly in a sentence to depict its meaning?

Comment: This is General Reference. Look up the definitions *and example usages* [in a dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forlorn)

Answer (score 3):

> The puppy lay in the ditch with a **forlorn** look on it's face.

or

> The **forlorn** puppy was in a ditch

and to depict the meaning of forlorn

> It looked like the puppy had been in the ditch for a while, he was lost, sad, lonely, totally without hope and utterly **forlorn**, I expect he would have just lain down to die had I not picked him up.

Comment: comment. In this wise what is the meaning of forlorn in this context?

Comment: sad, dismal, lost, abandoned, without hope ... all those nasty things you'd not want to see in the face of a cute little puppy. But I see what you mean, the OP asked for a way to use it to depict it's meaning, which I have not. Allow me to try another sentence